# athena - using max function for each column data

Tags: sql, max, amazon-athena, presto

Is there any way of using a function per info on column?
I have a column named env and it has two types of data its either 'eu' or 'us'
and I also have a column of timestamp. I need a way to show the max timestamp per env in each column with single query.

Is there any way of doing something like that?

my table:

```
session                             timestamp       env
4753f3feb27087c8f4c4bd79ad5cff55    1617570800000   US
5f08a8b6347ac27d93a6ea2f42f090b5    1617560800000   EU
bcab7e0a9f0af4b2e9cde11d36dc2e8a    1617580800000   EU
bcab7e0a9f0af4b2e9cde11d36dc2e8a    1617520800000   US
```

what i want

```
max_eu_ts        max_us_ts
1617580800000    1617570800000
```

Comment: Please share your sample input and desired output in text format.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur added an example

Comment: it's much clear now. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you just need to use `max(timestamp)`. One for `eu` and another is for `us`.
With `case when` statement you can select max(timestamp) only from rows having `us` in `env` column to calculate max_us_ts. Same for max_eu_ts.

```
select 
max(case when env='eu'then timestamp end) max_eu_ts ,
max(case when env='us' then timestamp end) max_us_ts    
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

You you just looking for `group by`?

```
select env, max(timestamp)
from t
group by env;
```

Or, if you want complete rows, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by env order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sadly that's not what i need. I added an example.

Comment: What is the difference between getting two lines or getting two columns? You can transpose the answer.